# TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Имею данные Json в переменной data:

```
{
  "response": {
    "count": 37,
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 4181139,
        "body": "текст1"
      },
      {
        "id": 4181793,
        "body": "текст2"
      }
    ],
    "in_read": 4630152,
    "out_read": 4630152
  }
}
```

Пытаюсь добавить их в список что бы потом использовать:

```
data = await self.api.messages.getHistory(user_id=msg.user_id)  
ids = []
for message in data:
    ids.append(str(message['items'][0]['id']))

await self.api.messages.delete(message_ids=','.join(ids), delete_for_all=1)
```

Но ошибка в шапке, помогите пожалуйста(

Comment: Что вы ожидаете внутри переменной `message`?

Comment: Что бы в ids вписался список из всех id которые в items --> типо: ["id1", "id2"]

Comment: Вообще-то я про переменную `message` спрашивал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ids = [item["id"] for item in data["response"]["items"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
str(message['response']['items'][0]['id']))
```